# Reading external JSON column in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below JSON from source and I have to read the key `x` which is a string as JSON  and also `timestamp`.

```json
{
 x: "y: \"Apple\", z: \"Mango\"",
 timestamp: 2022-04-04 19:00:00
},
{
 x: "y: \"Pineapple\", z: \"Pear\"",
 timestamp: 2022-04-04 21:00:00
}
```

I have the following code to extract the JSON from the string `x`.

```py
raw_df = spark.read.json('/my-file.json')
raw_df = spark.read.json(raw_df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.x))
```

But with the above code, I miss out on the `timestamp`. Is there a way to read the `x` and also its associated `timestamp` together in a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

> read the x and also its associated timestamp together in a dataframe

You only need

```
spark.read.json('/my-file.json').show()
```

But also, you don't have a valid JSON since `x` and `timestamp` (key + value) need quotes. And it's not JSONlines format, which SparkSQL needs (unless you set `.option("multiLine", true)` while reading.
If you do control the format, then each object should be on its own (single) line, with no commas in between lines/objects

> extract the JSON from the string x.

Within the `x` string, there is also not valid JSON (you are missing curly braces), but that would be this, for example

```
raw_df.select("x.*").show()
```

Comment: That JSON should be fine with `multiLine` `true` option.

Comment: @Emma Not without quoting the `x` and `timestamp`

Comment: ah yeah. that's true.  no quoting on key plus the datetime in value is not even a valid regular JSON.